# Excel bug: TEXT function doesn't work to extract day name depending on region

Tags: excel, date, formatting

How to compute day name from date in Excel?

Please don't say it is `TEXT(...,"ddd")` because it doesn't work

[image]

---

Another screenshots for non-believers:

[image]

---

[image]

---

Complete formula just doesn't work too:

[image]

---

This is some problem with locale processing. Although my Windows in English, my region is Russia and Excel uses it in some strange places:

[image]

Comment: If `TEXT(...;"ddd")` doesn't work, it means your dates aren't actually Excel DateSerials, they're just text that *look* like dates.  You'll need to convert from text to an actual date, and then the `TEXT(...;"ddd")` will work.

Comment: Using your provided image, this might work for you: `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B3;".";"/"));"ddd")`

Comment: @tigeravatar no, you are wrong, my dates ARE Excel serials, see new screenshot

Answer (score 1):

```
TEXT(...,"ddd")  (  or   TEXT(...;"ddd")  . as required   )
```

does work, provided you either SUBSTITUTE the dots `.` in your data for recognisable date separators first (eg `/`) or apply Find/Replace for that purpose. Though having done either (perhaps working on a copy) no formula is necessary since merely a Custom format of:

```
dddd
```

(long form, or `ddd` short) should be sufficient.

Note that without indication of the century Excel will guess which and not give you the right answer for a date such as 11.11.1911 (Armistice Day, a Saturday) represented in text as 11.11.11.

With string parsing you would need to be careful whether `10.08` represents October 8 on your system, or August 10.

Comment: I don't use dots in the formula, see screenshots please.

Comment: So, Excel is not region portable?

Answer (score 1):

We can always manually build one : `=if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=7,"Sunday",if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=6,"Saturday",if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=5,"Friday",if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=4,"Thursday",if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=3,"Wednesday",if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=2,"Tuesday",if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=1,"Monday","")))))))`

[^_^]